# How to access gallery folder on an android device

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to retrieve a video or image from the gallery folder. In my honeycomb tablet I don't have a sdcard. Can anybody tell me how to retrieve the image or video in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `MediaStore` content provider to find indexed media on the device. The Gallery application, for example, uses `MediaStore` -- there is no "gallery folder".